# Is it true that one has very less chances of getting liberated in Kaliyuga?

Tags: belief, moksha, kali-yuga

Recently, saw one blog saying that it is next to impossible to attain moksha/liberation from samsara in Kaliyuga pertaining to the influence of kali and not following dharmas as mentioned in vedas.